# Delete File, If End Characters Don't Match

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, match, matching, string-matching

I am trying to delete files from `/Dir1` that don't exist in `/Dir2`. The problem is that the first few characters match, but not the last few. For example.

```
/Dir1
abc_def.png
xyz_xyz.png

/Dir2
abc_ghi.png
```

So as long as "abc" matches, I don't want to delete the file even though the last few characters are different. The only file I want to delete is `xyz.png` because it does not exist in `/Dir2`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What if `/Dir2` had the file `ghi_abc.png` instead? Would `abc_def.png` in `/Dir1` not be deleted?

Comment: Correct, it would not be deleted. I want it to be dependent on the first three characters.

Comment: Dependent you mean on the first part of the filename before the underscore for files in  `/Dir1`?

Comment: Yes, the first part of the filename.

Comment: So if `/Dir1` has the file `1234_test.png` and `/Dir2` has `test_5678.png` then the file in `/Dir1` will be deleted — just confirming that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, the file would be deleted from `/Dir1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match part of filename before first underscore (as in your example), you can use this code:

```
cd /Dir1

for f in *_*; do
    [[ -f /Dir2/"${f%%_*}"* ]] || echo rm "$f"
done
```

Once satisfied, remove `echo` before `rm`.

Comment: What does the `d%%` represent? Is that like a placeholder for whatever the characters are?

Comment: No, that ended up echoing all files.

Comment: I've just run a diff between an ls of each directory, but that also ends up removing all files because the last characters are different.

Comment: It has nothing to do with last characters. This script assumes you want to match part of filename before first underscore.